# Ubuntu 14.04, wifi connection but no Internet, no usb recognized, can't shut down or restart properly

Tags: wireless, usb, shutdown, reboot

Sometimes Ubuntu is amazing, other times it makes me want to rip my hair.

So I have a laptop, hp pavillon g6 séries with Ubuntu 14.04 installed from a couple months ago, after struggling with the installation, finally got something workable, everything was fine until today I was going to connect my USB mouse and didn't work, so I tried rebooting but i got stuck in the little dots shutting off, so I held the button 5s, now, not only the USB ports don't work or the reboots / shutdown, now I'm connected to my wi-fi but can't open any pages.

Help, request me any information you might need but do so indicating step by step, because i'm not very good with Linux.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't include much about your problem and given that you claim not to be very good with Linux, I would recommend the following:

Create an Ubuntu live USB using another computer with Windows or Ubuntu.
Use it to backup all your data.

Unplug your new USB mouse and connect your laptop to internet with an ethernet cable. 
Open a console and type the following to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04

`sudo do-release-upgrade`

Hopefully your problem will go away after the upgrade.

Comment: Yea but computer doesn't read any usb inputs while in session, usb mouses or keyboards, flashdrives or cellphones, no media nor hardware are being recognised, i tried to plug the live usb with 14.04 to see if it would recognise after boot and it worked but passed the grub, into the actual session, no usb peripheral is recognised.

Comment: If the problem with USBs happens in the live system, I would recommend to reset the BIOS settings to the default.